# how to add content-type to Twilio response?

Tags: twilio, asp.net-web-api

How to add content-type to Twilio Response? I am getting 502 bad gateway error and the error says that it could be because of missing Content-Type. But I do see that the response has the Content-type. So what could be going wrong? I am also seeing the twilio reason is connection-time out! What does that mean? This is related to my earlier post at: [An attempt to retrieve content from returned the HTTP status code 502. Please check the URL and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157291/an-attempt-to-retrieve-content-from-returned-the-http-status-code-502-please-ch)

```
 Response - The HTTP headers and body of your server's response to Twilio

 Headers

 Content-Type   text/html
 Transfer-Encoding  chunked
 X-Twilio-Reason    connection timed out
 Body

 1
 <html><head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head><body><h1>Bad Gateway</h1>An upstream server returned an invalid response.</body></html>
```

Can somebody help me to find out why twilio is giving error while accessing my API? 
This is what I have in my controller:

```
      public class TestController : ApiController
{      
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage  Post([FromBody]SmsRequest smsReq)
    {

        string smsReqUpper = smsReq.Body.ToUpper();
        string testString = "TEST";
        var response = new Twilio.TwiML.TwilioResponse();

        if (smsReqUpper == testString)
        {                               
            response.Sms("Test Successful");
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.Element);

        }
        else
        {
            string strBody = "Invalid Text Command. Please text the word TEST " ;
            response.Sms(strBody);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.Element);

            //return new TwiMLResult(response);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I am still stuck and Twilio is still giving errors. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is the above code atleast correct?

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Type   text/html` bit refers to the 502 bad gateway response, not the actual response coming from your server. Add the "text/xml" content type to your request (I don't recognize the framework you are using) and you should be good to go.

To debug your response you can use `curl -vvv [URL]` until the `Content-Type: text/xml` part is present.