# Why is an Enum represented in two different ways in an API request?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, xml, enums

I guess that will be a duplicated question because it's something quite basic, but after some search I was not able to find the answer.

I have a .net462 application. I have the following enum:

```
 public enum Test
 {
     Foo,
     Bar,
 }
```

and the following endpoint in one controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("myTest")]
 public IEnumerable<Test> GetMyFooTest()
 {
     return new List<Test> { Test.Bar, Test.Foo };
 }
```

Now, if I use chrome to retrieve data from the endpoint, I get:
[image: Browser screenshot]

Here the Enums appear in its string form.

However, when I call this endpoint from the front end (JS, jQuery), or if I call it using Postman, I get:
[image: Postman screenshot]

No matter if I visualise it with JSON, XML or any option:
[image: options]

Here I get the numerical values of the Enums.

Why this difference? Is there a way to get the string values in the front end? (of course I have the option to change the controller to return a `IEnumerable<string>` and use a `ToString()` on the c# side, but that would be quite ugly...).

Comment: do those hidden headers ask for a specific format?

Comment: I ask why I get two apparently different answers. In Postman there is also the XML view and I don't get the same results as the XML in the browser. I'd like to see the strings in Postman the same way I see them from the browser.

Comment: Send the appropriate `Accept` header then. This seems to be nothing to do with how the enum is represented.

Comment: Check the header in both browser and postman to find the difference?

Comment: Ok, in postman I have Content-Type: application/json. That's it. I knew it was goint to be something basic... Thank you all!

Comment: If you want to enforce XML always (remove JSON support), you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250098/disable-json-support-in-asp-net-mvc-web-api). Having both allows the browser/client to request the response format (e.g. `Accept: application/xml` or `Accept: application/json`).

Comment: I marked the question as a duplicate but I didn't delete it in case it can help someone who don't use the right search words as I did. However, I found another duplicate question that has even better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2441290/11241615